# Paypal REST Api Internal Server Error

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm in a pickle with PayPal's new (and nice) REST Api. I am able to make many calls to the Paypal REST sandbox successfully. However, there are random times it won't work for short perdiods at all and the response code is **Internal Server Error **

Is this because I'm using a Sandbox? Or am I testing it too often? Is there a log stored for my account where I can see why the sandbox returned this error?

Here are the credit cards Im generally testing with.

```
4000000000000002 
4417119669820331
```

It's sporadic, and unpredictible if it will work or not. Is anyone else having this issue?

Here is the response:

```
debug_id: 394271a164c9
name: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
```

Comment: anyway you can provide us the Debug-Id from the response header when it happens next time ? That would help us troubleshoot what's going on. Meanwhile I will check with our ops to see if we find anything on our side. Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I have captured the debug_id: 394271a164c9

Comment: just a quick update- I was able to locate your api call in sandbox and it appears like it happened due to DB timeout. We are working with our operations team to figure out what's going on. It seems to be very sporadic as you've mentioned.

Comment: Is this a Sandbox Only issue, or a live one as well?

Comment: Sandbox Only - not in live.

Comment: @Praveen I see such an issue on Live site, debug_id=4e7fd31d51e7a